# creating xml doc from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i want to create xml doc based on database record i have coded these line but i don't know how to put parent node in it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
//header("Content-Type: text/plain");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($dtrs)) {
    //create sub toping..

    $root = $dom->createElement("case");
    $dom->appendChild($root);

    // create child element
    $caseno = $dom->createElement("caseno");
    $root->appendChild($caseno);

    // create text node
    $caseno_text = $dom->createTextNode($row[0]);
    $caseno->appendChild($caseno_text);


    // create child element
    $petname = $dom->createElement("petname");
    $root->appendChild($petname);

    // create text node
    $pet_text = $dom->createTextNode($row[1]);
    $petname->appendChild($pet_text);

    // create child element
    $resname = $dom->createElement("resname");
    $root->appendChild($resname);

    // create text node
    $res_text = $dom->createTextNode($row[2]);
    $resname->appendChild($res_text);

    // create child element
    $hearing = $dom->createElement("hearing");
    $root->appendChild($hearing);

    // create text node
    $hear_text = $dom->createTextNode($row[3]);
    $hearing->appendChild($hear_text);


    // create child element
    $status = $dom->createElement("status");
    $root->appendChild($status);

    // create text node
    $status_text = $dom->createTextNode($row[4]);
    $status->appendChild($status_text);
}
```

i get the Result like this where i am not able to put  node in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <case> <caseno>010301</caseno> <petname>ashiq</petname> <resname>state</resname> <hearing>8012-08-02</hearing> <status>P</status> </case> <caseno>010302</caseno> <petname>hussain</petname> <resname>state</resname> <hearing>8012-08-02</hearing> <status>P</status> </case>
```

actually i want my result like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <stage> <case> <caseno>010301</caseno> <petname>ashiq</petname> <resname>state</resname> <hearing>8012-08-02</hearing> <status>P</status> </case> <caseno>010302</caseno> <petname>hussain</petname> <resname>state</resname> <hearing>8012-08-02</hearing> <status>P</status> </case> </stage>
```

please help me out.

Comment: <stage><case>
<caseno>010301</caseno>
<petname>ashiq</petname>
<resname>state</resname>
<hearing>8012-08-02</hearing>
<status>P</status>
</case>
<caseno>010302</caseno>
<petname>hussain</petname>
<resname>state</resname>
<hearing>8012-08-02</hearing>
<status>P</status>
</case></stage>

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple root elements. You need to assign one root element outside the loop, and append you `case` elements to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cases>
    <case>
        <caseno>010301</caseno>
        <petname>ashiq</petname>
        <resname>state</resname>
        <hearing>8012-08-02</hearing>
        <status>P</status>
    </case>
    <case>
        <caseno>010302</caseno>
        <petname>hussain</petname>
        <resname>state</resname>
        <hearing>8012-08-02
        </hearing>
        <status>P</status>
    </case>
</cases>
```

Also, as an aside:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: i have put  <stage> element outside the loop but it is not appended.please edit my php code. i need exactly the same result which you have edited  <<thanks for helping me>>

Comment: @SajadA: You need to append all of the `<case>` elements to that `<stage>` root element, and not to the DOM object itself.

Comment: thanks @Madara actually i was doing wrong. and Inshallah i will use PDO instead of direct quering.